# If playback doesn’t begin shortly, try restarting your device

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, video, alsa

Please help guys. I get this annoying error whenever I play any video. It buffers for 10 seconds and then starts. Buffering is there whenever I play any video but error only shows in youtube. When I pause and play it still buffers and shows this error. Internet is not the issue. I tried 3-4 browsers including firefox but no solution. There is some problem in audio because when I play video on mute, it plays and when I unmute it again starts to buffer and display the same error.  I think there is some issue with audio drivers. When I try to install additional drivers it tells no additional drivers available for this device. Please tell if you require any info to solve this. I have tried many things to solve this but no solution. I have disabled hadware acceleration and installed multiple softwares and ran many terminal codes. Also I am completely new to Ubuntu so please tell every step to me. I dont want to switch back to windows!!

---

I did not found any solution to this however if you keep pulseaudio or volume mixer open in background it wont cause any problem.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Did it use to work and stopped? What drivers did you try to install? You have not supplied any info that could be used to help. What have you tried?

Comment: @David I am using Ubuntu Studio. It never worked. I just went to additional drivers in Software & Updates but it says no additional drivers available. Thank you for comment and sorry I dont know much about Linux. If you want me to run a code and give you output, I can do that.

Comment: @David I have tried restarting pulseaudio. And in youtube I saw a tutorial where he told me to change some text in pulseaudio files. I tried some more things I dont know what they were or what they did. I installed also gstreamer but I have no idea what it is.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and the solution for me was uninstalling PulseAudio and installing Pipewire.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue for the past couple of weeks. I fixed it by installing my Nvidia drivers and rebooting.
You can go through these links below, I hope they will be helpful.

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/#verification

https://techcult.com/fix-if-playback-doesnt-begin-shortly-try-restarting-your-device/